# Can the Rails Console be reloaded when release symlink changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symlink, irb, rails-console

I am running rails on a Capistrano-based deployment setup. I prefer to leave rails console sessions open in tmux, and have them persistently available.

Capistrano puts the application in a director named `releases/201304251515` (or the current time), and creates a symlink to that named `current/`. 
I run `rails console` from inside `current/`.

I am seeking a way to issue a `reload!` command that reloads the application from the new target of `current/`. It doesn't appear to do so, and changing Rails.application.config.root doesn't change the current working directory (`` `pwd` ``). Any ideas?

Comment: I usually exit the rails console and cd ../current then restart it after a deploy.  Would be interested if there is an alternative, but I live with it.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I do. I just have to make very sure that I've remembered to do that after a deploy.